# Socket Timeout Issue: android client reading data from pc server

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm new to android, java and socket programming so of course I'm trying to merge all three!

I'm creating a desktop based java server which will simply send a short string to an android app(client).

I have the android app running fine and it sends strings to the server which are read with no problems.

I have the server running and it recieves the strings with no problems.

The app(client) however has a socket timeout whenever I try to read the strings returned from the server. I'm using the same code so I can't understand the problem.

Anyway here's the code:

```
//SERVER//

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GpsServer {

    ServerSocket serversocket = null;
    Socket socket = null;

    public GpsServer() 
    {
        try
        {
            serversocket = new ServerSocket(8189);
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException unhe) 
        {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshServer() {

        try 
        {
            socket = serversocket.accept();

            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
            PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

            System.out.println("socket read successful");
            printwriter.println("Send Bye to disconnect.");

            String lineread = "";
              boolean done = false;
              while (((lineread = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) && (!done)){
                System.out.println("Received from Client: " + lineread);
                printwriter.println("You sent: " + lineread);
                if (lineread.compareToIgnoreCase("Bye") == 0) done = true;
              }

            System.out.println("Closing connection");

            socket.close();
            bufferedreader.close();
            inputstreamreader.close();
            printwriter.close();
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException unhe) 
        {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedIOException intioe)
        {
            System.out
                    .println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void nullify() {     
        try 
        {
            socket.close();
            serversocket.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and the client...

```
//CLIENT

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GpsClient {

    public String lastMessage;
    Socket socket = null;

    String serverurl;
    int serverport;

    public GpsClient() {
        lastMessage = "";

        serverport = 8189;
        serverurl = "192.168.10.4";

        try 
        {
            socket = new Socket(serverurl, serverport);
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException unhe) 
        {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void retrieveNew() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverurl, serverport);
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);

            lastMessage = "connected!";

            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.println("Request");

            lastMessage = "Request sent";

//          Get error when I uncomment this block, i.e. try to read the response from the server
//          "Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection."

//          String lineread = "";
//          while ((lineread = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
//              System.out.println("Received from Server: " + lineread);
//              lastMessage = "Received from Server: " + lineread;
//          }

            lastMessage = "closing connection!";
            bufferedreader.close();
            inputstreamreader.close();
            printwriter.close();
            socket.close();

        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException unhe) 
        {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + unhe.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedIOException intioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection.");
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe) 
            {
                System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void nullify() {
        try 
        {
            PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
            printwriter.println("Bye");
            printwriter.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Josh

Comment: Your messages are all wrong. All the messages "Timeout while attempting to establish socket connection" are incorrect. The first one can't even happen; the second one is a timeout either accepting or reading from a connection; the third one is a read timeout. In general you shouldn't substitute exception messages with your own made-up text. And in fact you should be catching `SocketTimeoutException,` not `InterruptedIOException.` Also you are printing 'socket read successful' before you have done any reads. Try cleaning all this up and re-test. At the moment your program is just lying to you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the issues noted in my comment, you are creating two sockets in the client, and your server is only written to process one connection. So it writes to the first one and tries to read from it, meanwhile your client is writing to the second one and trying to read from that.

When you fix that you will then hit a deadlock, as both sides are trying to read from each other.

Also you shouldn't use `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` over the network, as they swallow exceptions you need to know about. Use `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: Like I said I'm very new to socket programming. Most of that code is a patchwork of code I've found online, none of which has worked. You sound like you know your stuff EJP, would you mind giving an example of a very basic working bit of socket code that I could build upon because so far google has not been my friend :(.                                                                                                                                     P.S. I cleaned up the catch exceptions and used a bufferedwriter like you said. Still no dice :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting something at the end of the server message, like [ETX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character) or something like `<end>` or wrap the message in `<msg>...</msg>`.

Then on Android in the while loop check if you received it instead of checking `(lineread = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null`.